# uploading all files of a certain extension type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to upload all files of type .flv to an S3 bucket using the AWS CLI from a Windows server 2008 command line.

I do this:

`aws s3 sync . s3://MyBucket --exclude '*.png'`

And it begins uploading `.png` files instead.

I'm trying to follow the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html) and it gives an example that reads:

```
Local directory contains 3 files:
MyFile1.txt
MyFile2.rtf
MyFile88.txt
'''
aws s3 sync . s3://MyBucket/MyFolder --exclude '*.txt'
upload: MyFile2.rtf to s3://MyBucket/MyFolder/MyFile2.rtf
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may find that [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) is a much less painful command line option for Windows users.

Comment: @HyperAnthony Now I need to learn PowerShell... See my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918359/uploading-all-files-of-a-specific-type-to-s3-with-powershell

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://MyBucket/ --exclude "*" --include "*.flv"
```

It excludes all files, then includes .flv files. The order of parameters is important.

You can also use:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://MyBucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.flv"
```

The difference is that `sync` will not re-copy an identical file that already exists in the destination.

Comment: Note: `sync` will re-copy if the files are outdated. E.g., if you made a change to a file on your local, and did a sync, that file will get uploaded even if a file with the same name already exists in your destination bucket.

Comment: What if you want to include several file types, i.e. .txt and .tsv ?

Comment: @gaelgarcia You can add multiple `--include` parameters. See: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)