# How to upload all files of a specific type to S3 Bucket?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

When I do this:

```
foreach ($f in (Get-ChildItem -filter "*.flv")){
    Write-S3Object -BucketName bucket.example -File $f.fullName -Key $f.name -CannedACLName PublicRead
}
```

I get this error:

```
Write-S3Object :
At line:1 char:51
+  foreach ($f in (Get-ChildItem -filter "*.flv")){ Write-S3Object -BucketName xx. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Objec
   t], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I can do to see more of the error, or is this just a syntax issue?

How can I otherwise upload all of a certain filetype to a bucket using powershell?

### EDIT:

I  intentionally set `Set-DefaultAWSRegion` to a region that the bucket wasn't in, and got

```
Write-S3Object : The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

as an error message, as expected, so it looks like it can connect to the bucket and it knows that it isn't in a certain region.

Also, if I enter the  `s3://` prefix before the bucket name, I get a message that the bucket couldn't be found, so it it looks like what I'm entering now is correct.

I can do Get-S3Bucket and see all of the buckets on my account, so I know that it's configured correctly.

### EDIT2:

If I do:

```
> $f = Get-ChildItem -filter "*.flv"
> Write-S3Object

cmdlet Write-S3Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
BucketName: bucket.name
Key: $f[0].name
File: $f[0].fullName
Write-S3Object : The file indicated by the FilePath property does not exist!
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-S3Object
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCmdlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Objec
   t], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

If I do `$f[0].fullName` seperately, I get the full path to the object.
However, this has spaces in it. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Everything looks fine except for maybe the -BucketName parameter. Is that something you have to set up in S3?

Comment: @TimFerrill `bucket.name` is an example. It's actually the actual bucket name, minus the `s3://` prefix.

Comment: Another issue with this statement (happened to me), is the CannedACLName option. In the docs it's provided as "-CannedACLName PublicRead", but this results in the same error as above. It needs to read "-CannedACLName public-read".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fill in missing parameters like that from the command line, you need to specify their literal string values.  When I mimicked your issue locally:

```
PS C:\> Write-S3Object

cmdlet Write-S3Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
BucketName: MyTestBucketNameHere
Key: $testName
File: C:/test.txt
```

I ended up with a file on S3 whose key was named `$testName`, because variables aren't evaluated in that context. Likewise, you're getting this *"The file indicated by the FilePath property does not exist!"* error because there is no file in your filesystem named `$f[0].fullName`.

An example to write a single file to S3:

```
PS C:> Write-S3Object -BucketName "MyTestBucketName" -Key "file.txt" -File "C:/test.txt"
```

To write all of your files to S3:

```
PS C:\> (Get-ChildItem -filter "*.flv") | % { Write-S3Object -BucketName "MyTestBucketName" -File $_ -Key $_.name}
```

This will first get all files with the flv file-type in your current directory, and for each object (represented by the percent sign) we will write the file (represented by `$_`) to MyTestBucketName with a Key that is the name property of the current file being iterated.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter -CannedACLName PublicRead is not correct, correct parameter is

`foreach ($f in (Get-ChildItem -filter "*.flv")){
Write-S3Object -BucketName bucket.example -File $f.fullName -Key $f.name -CannedACLName public-read
}`

This fixed the issue for me and should fix for you as well.

Comment: Thank you. The wrong name presents in Amazon docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-s3-upload-object.html Correct names are listed on this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of these solutions worked so what I found is this.

When you're in Powershell ISE (4.0) it doesn't matter how you send the local filename, it will know its location, which means you can simply do this, in my example I'm trying to upload all the backups of a folder named e:\Backups to a bucket in S3:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Backups

foreach ($f in $results) { 

  $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($f)

  Write-S3Object -BucketName bi-dbs-daily-backup -File $f -Key $filename

}
```

If I run this in Powershell ISE everything works fine, but If I create a .ps1 and try to run it with the Task Scheduler I get: The file indicated by the FilePath property does not exist!

It turns out that when Windows tries to run the .ps1 it does it basically from the CLI, and when it does, it stops recognizing the path of the files you're sending.

So I added | % { $_.FullName } to GetChildItem to get the fullpath of each file and now everything works fine:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Backups **| % { $_.FullName }** 

foreach ($f in $results) { 

  $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($f)

  Write-S3Object -BucketName bi-dbs-daily-backup -File $f -Key $filename

}
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

For other newbs out there looking for a script that does this but not for public access remove the -CannedACLName public-read altogether.  Took me 2 frustrating hours to figure that out.  :)